# Can I open a new window in Javascript and click an element in that window?

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is create a button on a website of mine, that when clicked, launches a website called toggl (which is a website for timing how long it takes to complete tasks ect) then takes information from my current website, i.e. the title of what im working on, copies it into the toggl form, and clicks the button to start the timer.

I've been researching and playing around and I feel like there might be some obvious security risks in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with a browser, you either have to create a server to [scrape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) off toggl -which is pretty hacky-, or look for a toggl API, which [this](https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/toggl_api.md) might just be, and consume it as you need it.

Comment: okay, thats a whole new level of confusion for me, can JSON requests, as the API suggest to use, be made from my website to open toggle with the information i pass into it?

Comment: They can be, yes, using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), but the problem with that is, when you request on a client (which basically means your browser), you can get issues with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). A way to avoid possible CORS issues, is creating a server, which requests to the API without problems, since servers do not get CORS issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (with my own limited knowledge of javascript), without using a browser extension, this is not possible. Your initial website and Toggl are on separate domains and as such, their interaction is limited (or non-existent, without modification on both sides).

As for filling out the forms, you may be able to fill them out using parameters in the redirecting url (assuming you are able to find out what they need to be), but you still wouldn't be able to automatically click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can like:

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings')
```

jQuery:

```
$('a#link_id').click(function(){
  window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
  return false;
});
```

You could also set the `target` to `_blank` actually.

Answer (score 0):

there's actually no way to make 2 different pages or windows communicating with js, that because of security issues.

In normal situations, those sites you see that do something like you are looking for, uses a back-end server app that communicate with socket connections (or other kind) with those pages.

Java EE uses soap to communicate with a server session.

Something you're able to do is create a "overlapping" form in which loading another page (eg. with AJAX) and retrieving data once that page is close (or runtime, as you prefere)

generally this is done creating a fixed position form large the entire window that prevents default input to propagate, then loading the page content in there.

hope that helps :)